# Redirect on the same port from http to https with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, https, apache-virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a website setup `http://mydomain.com/myroject` on ubuntu 14.04(apache webserver)

I setup htsql service on the same host to run on port 5000

```
working links:
http://mydomain.com/myproject
http://mydomain.com:5000/region
```

Then I installed ssl cert on this server to run the website through `https`

`https://mydomain.com/myproject` is working but `https://mydomain.com:5000/region` is not working because the port 5000 is already in use where htsql service is running on this port

Now the question is how do I redirect on the same port(5000) from http to https with nginx reverse proxy

In other words `https://mydomain.com:5000/region` should work

My idea is to setup a different port(eg: 5001) on nginx and forward the request to https, 5000 port.

Here are apache configuration files:

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerName mydomain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/project.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/project.key
</VirtualHost>
```

nginx configuration file:

default.conf

```
server {
        listen 5001 ssl;

        server_name my domain.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/project.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/project.key;
        error_page 497 301 =307 https://mydomain.com:5001$request_uri;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://mydomain:5000;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        }

}
```

Comment: If 5000/TCP is in use, you cannot use it for a 2nd purpose.

Comment: Apache is running on port 80 and 443 and serving `http(s)://mydomain.com/myproject`. The database is running on `http://mydomain.com:5000/region`. Correct me if I'm wrong. If you want an external connection to the database, you could use `http(s)://mydomain.com/region` (on port 80 and 443) and proxy the requests to `http://mydomain.com:5000/region` (internally) and close port 5000 in the firewall. No need for nginx. No need for an extra port 5001. See the [mod_proxy Reverse Proxy example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse).

Comment: @Freddy Where should I change the configuration in order to use http(s)://mydomain.com/region (on port 80 and 443) and proxy the requests to http://mydomain.com:5000/region?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Apache as a Reverse Proxy, make sure you have modules `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled in your server (e.g. `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`). Add `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to the bottom of your VirtualHost sections and you should be good.

Restart the server afterwards with `sudo service apache2 restart`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # added missing ServerName
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # should be disabled by default, just to make sure
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /region  http://mydomain.com:5000/region
    ProxyPassReverse /region http://mydomain.com:5000/region
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        # moved ServerName to the top
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # consider using separate log files for SSL
        #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-error.log
        #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-access.log combined

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/project.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/project.key

        # should be disabled by default, just to make sure
        ProxyRequests Off

        ProxyPass /region  http://mydomain.com:5000/region
        ProxyPassReverse /region http://mydomain.com:5000/region
</VirtualHost>
```